# Generating a true random number

Tags: javascript

There are posts in SO on how to generate a random number in Javascript. One common solution is:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

But if I set my min to 0 and max to 3 and refresh my web app, the vast majority of times this function will return 0. There is clearly no even distribution on the randomness generated.

Is there a better way than doing it like this?

Comment: There are very few "true" random generators, especially in clientside JS, but there are better ones, and this has been asked many time before

Comment: >> the vast majority of times this function will return 0. There is clearly no even distribution on the randomness generated
This is incorrect, as you can see by running a simple test:
    function rng(min, max) { return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; }
    let a = new Array(10).fill(0);
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i += 1) { let n = rng(0, 9); a[n] += 1; }
    console.log(a);

Comment: There is an crypto API in JavaScript which you might be interested in.